# Force CPAN to download via HTTP (skipping proxy)

Tags: http, perl, cpan

I'm about to lose my mind.  How in the world do you tell CPAN to download via HTTP only?  ...and NOT via a proxy.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way of having it not use FTP is to shove HTTP URLs on the front of your urllist - or replace it completely like sebastionopilla said. You can do it from inside the cpan shell too:

```
o conf urllist unshift http://some.cpan.mirror/here/
```

You can use

```
o conf urllist -
o conf urllist shift
```

to empty it first if you wish.

Use

```
o conf no_proxy 1
```

to turn off the proxy.

Use

```
o conf commit
```

to save the config

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

1. Before running cpan: `export -n http_proxy`
2. In the cpan shell: `o conf http_proxy ''`
3. To save your modified cpan config: `o conf commit`

That will disable any http proxy CPAN is configured to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting only HTTP URLs in your CPAN's Config.pm file, like:

```
'urllist' => [q[http://cpan.cict.fr/], q[http://cpan.enstimac.fr/], q[http://mirrors4.kernel.org/cpan/]],
```

I routinely do this and as far as I can see there's no FTP traffic to any CPAN mirror.

Answer (score 1):

```
cpan[1]> o conf /proxy/
cpan[2]> o conf no_proxy 1
cpan[3]> o conf commit
```

Set proxy username and password:

```
cpan[4]> o conf proxy_user your_username
cpan[5]> o conf proxy_pass your_password
cpan[6]> o conf commit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a cpan shell, you can also edit your cpan config file with a text editor, in unix systems it's here:

~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm

Of course, the field to change in your particular question is 'http_proxy'.